# Trouble with transfer method in purse program (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble perfecting a transfer method to transfer contents from 2 array lists. I am required to use a For-Each loop to do so, but at the moment the method only transfers the first item in the Array List and nothing more.

```
package assignment;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A purse holds a collection of coins
 *
 * @author type your name
 */
public class Purse {

    ArrayList<String> coins;
    ArrayList<String> rcoins;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty purse.
     */
    public Purse() {
        coins = new ArrayList<String>();
        rcoins = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a coin to the purse
     *
     * @param coinName the coin to add
     */
    public void addCoin(String coinName) {
        coins.add(coinName);
    }

    /**
     * Return a string describing the object
     *
     * @return a string in the format "Purse[coinName1, coinName2, ...]"
     */
    public String toString() {
        if (coins.size() == 0)
            return "Purse[]";

        String output = "Purse[";

        for (String coin : coins)
            output = output + coin + ", ";

        // remove the last ", " 
        output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 2);
        return output + "]";
    }

    public String reverse() {
        if (coins.size() == 0)
            return "Purse[]";

        String output = "Reverse Purse[";

        for (String coin : coins)
            rcoins.add(0, coin);

        for (String coin : rcoins)
            output += coin + ",";

        output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
        return output + "]";

    }

    public void transfer(Purse a, Purse b) {
        for (String coin : a.coins) {
            b.coins.add(coin);
            coins.remove(coin);
        }
    }

    public String sameContents(Purse a, Purse b) {
        String eq = "";
        int size;
        if (a.coins.size() > b.coins.size())
            size = b.coins.size();
        else
            size = a.coins.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (a.coins.get(i).equals(b.coins.get(i)))
                eq = "They are equal";
            else
                eq = "They are not equal";
        }
        return eq;
    }
}
```

My tester

```
package assignment;

public class PurseTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create new Purses
        Purse p = new Purse();
        Purse q = new Purse();

        //Add coins
        p.addCoin("Nickel");
        p.addCoin("Quarter");
        p.addCoin("Dime");
        q.addCoin("Penny");
        q.addCoin("Quarter");

        //Print contents of Purse P and the reversed contents
        System.out.println(p.toString());
        System.out.println("\n" + p.reverse());

        //Print contents of Purse Q
        System.out.println("\nOther " + q.toString() + "\n");

        //Call the transfer method to transfer the contents of Purse Q into Purse P
        q.transfer(q, p);

        //Print contents after transfer
        System.out.println(p.toString());
        System.out.println("Other " + q.toString());

        System.out.println("\n");
        //Compare purses P and Q to see if they share contents, print reslt
        System.out.println(p.sameContents(p, q));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void transfer(Purse a, Purse b)
{

    for(String coin : a.coins){
        b.coins.add(coin);
        coins.remove(coin);
}
```

Your mistake is on this line:

```
coins.remove(coin);
```

That's removing coins from the purse that belongs to `this` object, which is the same one you're transferring them to in your test code.  You add a coin, then immediately remove it from the same purse.  You should be removing them from purse `a`.

Since you're calling `transfer` on a `Purse` object, it would be better to only have one argument.  The `Purse` you call the method on should be the purse you're either taking from or transferring to, and the argument should be the other purse.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I had to keep 2 arguments in the method as part of the transfer required was to put all the contents into one purse and clear the other. I removed coins.remove(coin); and changed a.coins in the loop to just coins. For the removal I noticed there was a removeAll method already there so I used b.coins.removeAll(coins); after the For-Each loop and it worked perfectly in the tester. Thanks again!

Comment: @HDInfinity You're welcome. I was going to suggest either [`clear`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear%28%29) or `removeAll`, so that sounds like a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

In object oriented programming, your `transfer` method shoud look like:

```
// transfer coins from an other purse to this
public void transfer(Purse from) {
    for(String coin : from.coins){
        this.coins.add(coin);
        from.coins.remove(coin);
    }
}
```

In your original example, `coins.remove(coin);` would remove coins from `this.coins`, while you were transferring from `a` to `b`.

A method transferring from `Purse a` to `Purse b` like the one you wrote should probably have been defined static outside the `Purse` class since no reference is made to the current `Purse` `this`.